# Multicolumn layouts don't work when printing in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, css-multicolumn-layout

I've been working on making a printer-friendly version of a page full of events. We settled on having the page use multiple-columns CSS to save paper. Much to my surprise, Chrome has an override so that I can't use multi-columns when printing. Is there a reason for this, or is it a bug?

```
@media print {
    .list{
        -webkit-column-width: 20em;
        -moz-column-width: 20em;
        column-width: 20em;
        -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
        -moz-column-gap: 2em;
        column-gap: 2em;
    }
}
```

[image: Chrome overtaking the multi-columns with user agent stylesheets]

Comment: What happens if you write `-webkit-column-count: 3 !important` ?

Comment: There was a bug in Chrome with printing multicolumn containers, but it seems to have been fixed. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=99358

Comment: @litel That's very good news! As of this writing, I've just updated to Chrome 48 today and the issue is still present. Canary is crashing completely today, but perhaps these woes will be silenced. In other Webkit browsers, I wish we were so lucky. Opera and Safari have the issue too. :(